# Remove HTTP methods in Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel Resource routing (through a controller). Here is the routing code

```
Route::resource( 'difficulty', 'DifficultyController', [ 'only' => [ 'index', 'show', 'update', 'create' ] ] );
```

Here are the routes created

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name              | Action                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | difficulty              | difficulty.index  | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@index  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | difficulty/create       | difficulty.create | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@create |            |
|        | PATCH    | difficulty/{difficulty} |                   | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@update |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | difficulty/{difficulty} | difficulty.show   | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@show   |            |
|        | PUT      | difficulty/{difficulty} | difficulty.update | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@update |            |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

It works fine, except that I don't need the "HEAD" and "PATCH" methods and I want to remove them. So listing routes will display the following

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name              | Action                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET      | difficulty              | difficulty.index  | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@index  |            |
|        | GET      | difficulty/create       | difficulty.create | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@create |            |
|        | GET      | difficulty/{difficulty} | difficulty.show   | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@show   |            |
|        | PUT      | difficulty/{difficulty} | difficulty.update | App\Http\Controllers\DifficultyController@update |            |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Is it possible to do it? I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: It's possible but you'd need to extend Router and ResourceRegistrar and overwrite a few methods. I don't think it's worth the effort. Why do you need to remove them?

Comment: Because the supervisor will ask what is the purpose of HEAD and PATCH methods in there if you don't even use them. Just kidding.

Comment: I don't think there is a native way to do this. Just write them out manually or just ignore it.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo No technical reason. Just thinking of having less access points that I don't need.

Comment: @natzim How to write them out manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just doing explicit declarations?

```
Route::get('/difficulty','DifficultyController@index');
Route::get('/difficulty/create','DifficultyController@create');
Route::get('/difficulty/{difficulty}','DifficultyController@show');
Route::put('/difficulty/{difficulty}','DifficultyController@update');
```

I even prefer having it this way since it gives a clearer picture of what your application does.

Comment: This way you will get rid of PATCH, but Route::get() adds both GET and HEAD to your routing. Still, GET/HEAD should a single endpoint just behaving differently depending on the method - HEAD should return no content. So it should work, if defining much more routes is ok for OP.